# Are TCP/IP and UDP the only protocols supported by the Internet?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, protocols

Are TCP and UDP the only protocols supported by the Internet? If they are, do other networking protocols that are not meant to be used with common hardware exist?

Answer (score 1):

No, not at all. The Internet is routed at the network layer, which is IP.

The problem is that NAPT that is used for IPv4 because we have run out of those addresses only supports TCP, UDP, and ICMP. IPv6 restores the IP end-to-end paradigm and you can use any transport protocol because the Internet only cares about IP, not any protocols above that.